# Retrieving Query strings in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

For an already agreed (between customer and us) URL like,

```
http://URL/companyapi/orders/100191/sendrequest?for=customer123&card=123451
```

I am defining a route map like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Service",
                 routeTemplate: "companyapi/orders/{orderId}/{controller},
                 default: new{},
                 );
}
```

For retrieving other query string parameters, I think it is enough if I do this:

```
public void Get(string for, int card)
{
        // How to retrieve the orderId ?
}
```

**1. How to retrieve the `orderId` because it comes before `controller` portion in the route Template?**

**2.  Is it perfectly normal to leave the default part of the `MapRoute` function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add orderId parameter to Get Method.

```
public void Get(int orderId, string for, int card)
{
        // How to retrieve the orderId ?
}
```

and change RouteConfig.cs file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Service",
                 routeTemplate: "companyapi/orders/{orderId}/{controller},
                 default: new{},
                 );
}
```

to

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Service",
                 routeTemplate: "companyapi/orders/{controller},
                 default: new{},
                 );
}
```